# PowerShell process handling - Start multiple SqlPackage.exe processes in a PowerShell loop

Tags: windows, multithreading, powershell

Is there a way to start worker processes of SqlPackage.exe where the target databases are stored in an array such that you can loop over it (all other parameters are the same)?

I would like to suppress all prints from these processes UNLESS there's an error, and then show a report at the end. How would I do this?

Right now I have a loop like the following (as a start):

```
$arguments = @(
    "/Action:Import",
    "/SourceFile:$($bacpacSource)",
    "/TargetServerName:$($serverName)"
)

for ($i = 1; $i -lt 4; $i++) {
    $targetDatabase = $baseDatabaseName + $i
    $arguments += "/TargetDatabaseName:$($targetDatabase)"
    Start-Process -FilePath $sqlPackagePath $arguments -NoNewWindow -PassThru
}
```

I found the `Start-Process` somewhere and I am sure that I need to store the object returned by this function and use it somehow. I would like to start all the processes and then wait for all of them to finish, at which point I will investigate whether or not all succeeded. If there are failures I want to print the error information from that process. Right now all processes print at the same time and the whole buffer is corrupted after they all finish.

Is this possible in PowerShell?

PS: The script is meant to deploy updates using .dacpac files to production later, but this question is strictly related to the handling of Windows processes and errors.

EDIT: I will probably need a way to create and maintain a maximum amount of processes at once, and exchange when some are done. So let's say that at any moment I may only have 10 SqlPackage.exe processes connecting to the server. How would I create such a `barrier lock` (think that's what it's called) in PowerShell?

Comment: Have a look at jobs: http://wragg.io/tilfmol-4-powershell-jobs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could incorporate PowerShell Jobs as follows to push each task in to a background job and then use `Wait-Job` to wait for them to complete before returning their output via `Receive-Job`:

```
$arguments = @(
    "/Action:Import",
    "/SourceFile:$($bacpacSource)",
    "/TargetServerName:$($serverName)"
)

for ($i = 1; $i -lt 4; $i++) {
    $targetDatabase = $baseDatabaseName + $i
    $arguments += "/TargetDatabaseName:$($targetDatabase)"
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Start-Process -FilePath $sqlPackagePath $arguments -NoNewWindow -PassThru }
}

Get-Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

Comment: This is kind of what I right now after following your comment. I just need to figure out how to check whether any given job has crashed so I can check ExitCode and Error. Can I do that with jobs? Right now you wrapped it in a job, whereas I just switched it back to a previous version I had `& $sqlPackage $arguments` (and I also redeclare the param($arguments) in the ScriptBlock as it seems it doesn't have access to the outside scope and pass them with -ArgumentList (,$arguments))

Comment: After some experiments I think I'll have to have some kind of barrier approach, or a pool of workers and a set of tasks (that I can generate in the same way as up there).